# macOS - How to have NSSavePanel to add a file extension in the file name?

Tags: swift, macos, nssavepanel

I'm using this code to give the user the choice to specify a name and a location where to save a plain text file on disk. All seems to work but the saved file hasn't any extension. Actually I have not specify an extension in any part of my code, I read NSSavePanel documentation without notice the part where explained this option.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    let textToExport = mainTextField.textStorage?.string

    if textToExport != "" {
        let mySave = NSSavePanel()

        mySave.begin { (result) -> Void in

            if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
                let filename = mySave.url

                do {
                    try textToExport?.write(to: filename!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                } catch {
                    // failed to write file (bad permissions, bad filename etc.)
                }

            } else {
                NSBeep()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are a ton of topics just for NSSavePanel.  What's so unique about yours?

Comment: Thank you El Tomato, I edited the title, now is less generic

Comment: After having get the filename, have a look at it and add extension if needed.

Comment: Thank you, but I've to sandbox the app and I think I have to use the filename chosen by the user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the line

```
mySave.allowedFileTypes = ["txt"]
```

before presenting the panel.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nssavepanel/1534419-allowedfiletypes):

> The value of this property specifies the file types the user can save
>   the file as. A file type can be a common file extension, or a UTI. The
>   default value of this property is nil, which indicates that any file
>   type can be used. (Note that if the array is not nil and the array
>   contains no items, an exception is raised.)
>
> If no extension is given by the user, the first item in the
>   allowedFileTypes array will be used as the extension for the save
>   panel. If the user specifies a type not in the array, and
>   allowsOtherFileTypes is true, they will be presented with another
>   dialog when prompted to save.